# Callback for when a child dom element is inserted or has its class changed?

Tags: callback, ember.js

In Ember.js, I have a view that has

```
{{#if obj.property}}
    <div {{bindAttr class="prop"}}>content</div>
{{/if}}
```

How can I get called back for when this element is inserted into the view, and for when the class is attached onto the element? I want to do this because the CSS class is an animation class, and I'd like to hook onto the onAnimationEnd event of the element so that I get notified when the animation ends.

Answer (score 2):

How about changing the div to be a custom view subclass that implements didInsertElement? e.g.

```
{{#if obj.property}}
    {{view App.MyView}}
{{/if}}
```

and

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: "prop",
  didInsertElement: function() {
     // use this.$() to get a jQuery handle for the element and do what you'd like 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Luke's answer, I found out another way to achieve this, which may be preferable since creating a view is required for Luke's approach.

By exploiting the fact that DOM events bubble up, I can setup an event handler for animationEnd on a parent DOM element that contains whatever may be inserted. E.g.

```
<div id="container">
{{#if obj.property}}
    <div {{bindAttr class="prop"}}>content</div>
{{/if}}
</div>

// view.js
didInsertElment: function() {
    this.$('#container').bind('webkitAnimationEnd', function(e) {
        // e.target is the element whose animation ended.
    }
}
```